# Codeigniter Default Controller 403 Directory access is forbidden

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Im using php 5.6.40 and codeigniter 3.1.9 on Mac OS Catalina
myroutes :

```
$route['default_controller'] = "Homepenta";
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteEngine On


<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
Options All -Indexes
</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# This domain inherits the “PHP” package.
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

on browser

```
http:\\localhost\mastertransaksi\
```

show error

```
Directory Access is Forbidden
```

but if

```
http:\\localhost\mastertransaksi\Homepenta
```

its work

anyone can explation how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: I assume you mean `http://localhost/mastertransaksi/` (etc.) Where is your `.htaccess` file? What is your file structure?

Comment: .htaccess in root folder, /Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/htdocs/mastertransaksi/.htaccess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your `DirectoryIndex` is not set, or not set correctly (it defaults to `index.html` only). Add the following to the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Your mod_rewrite directives are not rewriting `/mastertransaksi/` to `/mastertransaksi/index.php` because this is a physical directory and your rule excludes directories.

The 403 results because directory indexes are disabled and no `DirectoryIndex` document is found.

*Aside:* You have multiple `RewriteEngine` directives which are unnecessary and should be removed. Also...

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine on
> Options All -Indexes
> </IfModule>
> ```

Remove the `<IfModule>` wrapper and `RewriteEngine On` directive. Just keep the `Options` directive.

Comment: I put DirectoryIndex index.php  on the top and removed <ifmodule> , Thanks @MrWhite . Its Work, it save my hours.